# Unable to load Pokemon Go on iPhone

Tags: pokemon-go, ios

I was in China and tried to load Pokemon Go. The sign in screen popped up and asked to sign in. However, I wasn't able to log in at all as the screen kept loading forever. When I came back to Hong Kong, I was not able to load the app anymore. The app just shut by itself as soon as I try opening it.

I cannot log in or get into the game no matter how long I let that screen load. The funny thing is that I'm able to log in and use the app on another device.

This is what I have tried:

- Deleting the application and reinstalling it.
- Restarting the phone.
- Turning off and on WiFi.
- Turning off and on Airplane Mode.
- Keeping the loading screen on for a LOOONG while.

Answer (score 2):

This is because China has blocked all of Google's services.

How Pokemon Go works is that it uses the Google Maps API to keep track of your location in real time. However, if it is blocked, then Pokemon Go cannot get your location.

If you can't log in, that's probably because you're trying to log in via Google. Again, China blocked Google's services, so you can't log in via Google.

Comment: While this seems like a plausible answer, do you have source to backup China blocking Google Services?

Comment: @Wondercricket I am Chinese (lol) but yeah, you can just google it. Quote from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_China): In November 2012, GreatFire.Org reported that China had blocked access to Google. The group reported that all Google domains, including Google search, Gmail, Google Maps, etc., became inaccessible. The reason for the blockage was likely to control the content in the nation's Internet while the government prepares to change leadership.